# Is there a way to check the histroy of a contract's table?

Tags: smart-contract, table, history

Is there a way to check the history after deleting the information in the table? For example, check yesterday's table information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can restore state of the specific point in the past by snapshot. You can download it from [here](https://eosnode.tools/snapshots), or you can accumulate all transactions related to the table you're interested in from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://docs.dfuse.io/#websocket-based-api-get_table_rows with listen: true, to consume every delta up from a specific start-block.